# android choice of correct layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am building a small app - a card game. I want to do some basic graphic on the screen:

a row of cards atop each other, where each card covers 90% of the previous card (and you can see only the suit and rank when the next card is added). I start with one card, then add another one which covers 90% and you see the whole second card, then the third covering 90% of the second ETC.

what layout would you recommend to use? both Relative and Linear won't seem to work and i don't want to use absolute..
EDITED!
hers the image: (only the middle part is relevant)
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: please draw your design in paint and put screen shot then i will help you.

Comment: I have edited and uploaded an image. thanks

Answer (score 1):

using `FrameLayout` will help you and the this link have the same issue

[Stacking image views with overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840616/stacking-image-views-with-overlapping)