# Stacking image views with overlapping and image fetching with sdcard

Tags: android

1.Stacking image views with overlapping and image fetching with Micro Secure Digital Card.

Visit [Stacking image views with overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840616/stacking-image-views-with-overlapping)

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: sir , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840616/stacking-image-views-with-overlapping

Comment: That's your question? O...k.

Comment: yes sir but i am using images with sdcard

Answer (score 0):

for stacking imageViews, either put them all inside a frameLayout or use a single imageView as shown here: [How to maintain multi layers of ImageViews and keep their aspect ratio based on the largest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on) .

image fetching can be done via the volley library.

about how to save to external storage, it depends on how you choose to show the images.

Comment: visit sir plz ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729169/how-to-maintain-multi-layers-of-imageviews-and-keep-their-aspect-ratio-based-on